# In geotools ,how to use Geometry as feature source add into layer?

Tags: java, geotools

In geotools ,how to use geometry as feature source add into layers?

I know that .shp file can add into layers, and add into content,then we can show it.
I read it in geotools quickstart:
http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/intellij.html

but I want to show the geometry object in content, I need to use geometry object as feature source replace shap file.(It's right?) 
So how to do it? I only konw that how to get geometry's WKT and geojson.

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GeoTools](https://geotools.org) will only display `Feature`s so you need to create a `Feature` and add your `Geometry` object to the feature. You will also need to know the projection of your geometry if you plan to display it with other data sets (e.g. shapefiles).

If you look at the [Feature Tutorial](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/feature/csv2shp.html) you will see a worked example of how to create a `FeatureType` and how to make `Feature`s using it. The [QuickStart tutorial](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/index.html) shows how to display features on the screen.

The utility class [`DataUtilities`](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/main/data.html) provides methods for converting lists of features to `FeatureCollections` and `FeatureSources`.

You mention WKT and GeoJSON as possible sources so you will want to explore the [`JTS.WKTReader`](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/io/WKTReader.html) and the [`gt-geojson`](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/unsupported/geojson.html) module for help parsing those formats into `Geometries` that GeoTools can make use of.

Comment: yes ，I konw that how to use Geometry to make a Feature ,but FeatureLayer need FeatureSource,I don't konw how to use Feature to make a FeatureSource,can you show me some code about that?